# C++: Problem with simple equation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 on Windows XP. My code is as follows:

```
# include "stdio.h"
void main () {
 int m,n;
 double sum=0;
 n=65536;
 sum=1.0/(n*n);
 printf("%.20lf",sum);
 return;
}
```

The output of my code is:

```
1.#INF0000000000000000
```

Why do I get the WRONG answer? How can I calculate `1/(65536*65536)` correctly? I'm expecting to get `0.00000000023283064365386962890625`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Double is not precise enough for that equation. You need something more precise, like a long long double.

Answer (score 5):

There is integer overflow. Your can just cast int to double before multiply:

```
sum=1.0/(((double)n)*n);
```

Answer (score 1):

n*n is too large for an integer to hold. make it double.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 32bit Integers n*n causes an overflow (4294311936).
An Integer ranges from

```
–2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647
```

You could try to declare n as `double n = 65536;`

Comment: Nitpickers would say you that it should be `double n = 65536.0;` (the `.0` specifies that it's a `double` literal and not an `int` literal).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting you can just do this:

```
double result = 1.0/n/n;
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the multiplication of two `int` variables overflows, because 65536*65536 does not fit into 32 bits. Try using `long long` or `double` for `m` and `n`.

Comment: `long long` dopesn't exist on VC6, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the double stars `**` but you need to use the `long` or `long long` type to hold integers of that size.

Comment: I believe that the stars (`**`) were part of the formatting of the original question, removed them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
sum=1.0/(n*n); 
by 
sum=1.0/(double)n/(double)n; 
the reason is an integer overflow (32 bit), followed by missing cast (secondary).